# Querying by a php a table containing emoji returns question marks

Tags: php, mysql, emoji

I am trying to retrieve a number of rows from a mysql DB, some of which containing emojis, through the following function:

```
<?php
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
//$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->query("SET character_set_client=utf8mb4");
$mysqli->query("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4");
$mysqli->query("SET character_set_results=utf8mb4");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$sth = $mysqli->query($query);
if (!$sth) error_log("error Json query: $query");
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
//var_dump($rows);
print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Yet each emoji occurrence is substituted by a variable number of question marks, yet
if I conversely execute the query of the php script directly on Sequel Pro, the emojis show correctly. Apparently there is therefore some error in the function above, but I tried anything, as you may see, without success.
How should the query be configured instead?

Comment: `$sth = $mysqli->query($query);` what is `$query` ?

Comment: Why do you have `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`? This overwrites the previous `utf8mb4` settings. Just use `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");` and remove the `SET character_set_*` queries (which are redundant).

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I made several experimentations and that was left.

Answer (score 0):

I thank Paul for the hint, the issue was related to the redundant use of:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

that apparently replaced the previous commands, taking it out the emojis showed just fine.